# What is the concept of knowing one's own abilities?

Tags: self, self-cognition

For example, I know that I am strong enough to pick up a feather, but that I am 
unable to lift up a car.

I'm unsure if this is self-awareness, because it does not cover the conscious knowledge of one's feelings. Any comments?

Comment: Isn't it just experience? You lifted several things in your life, you lifted a feather and noticed that you could. And one day you encountered something you could not lift (maybe a rock) and you know a car is heavier than that rock and so you know that you can't lift a car.

Comment: "A man's got to know his own limitations." -- Clint Eastwood in some spaghetti western.

Comment: See Gilbert Ryle's "knowledge-that" vs. "knowledge-how" distinction.

Answer (score -1):

I think knowing self is a key to many successes. You can have abilities in curriculum vitae, or in a computer game, or whenever you get known something, you achieve this ability.

You can have a path on which you plan your abilities, eg. learning plan. 
Then as motivation you have achieved an ability, like in this service you are achieving badges.

Ability is somehow benefiting from hard work or learning, because having ability make you at least satisfied.

There are at least two kinds of abilities:

- that you can't lose
- that you can lose

If I read a book and talk too much about it, I forget sometimes about that book. 
But when I learn to ride a bicycle, I cannot forget this ability.